# How can I set up multiple filters with pivot.js

Tags: jquery, filter, datatables, pivot

I want to use multiple filters with pivot.js
Its easy enough using different columns like this:

filters{'Animal':'Elephant','Colour':'Pink','Eyes':'2'} to give all the 2 eyed pink elephants

but if I need to create a set of filters like:--

filters{'Animal':'Elephant','Animal':'Giraffe','Animal':'Armadillo'}
to give Elephants, Giraffes and Armadillos but that just gives me back the last on 'Armadillos'

I have tried various ways of doing 'OR' statements but none have worked

Answer (score 0):

OK I figured it out after all

Firstly the filter type needs to be set to regexp so we can filter with regular expressions

{name:'Animal', type:'string', filterable:true, **filterType:'regexp'**}

Then the filter needs to us a regular expression like so

filters{'Animal':**/Elephant|Giraffe|Armadillo/**}